# Can the word “Schlange” refer to a “dragon”?

Tags: meaning, lyrics, ambiguity

In my German/English dictionary, the primary translation for “Schlange” is:

> snake, serpent

In English, the word “serpent” usually refers to a “snake”, but it can also refer to a “dragon” (or another similar mythological reptile).

**Is the German word “Schlange” just as ambiguous as “serpent” is in English; can it refer to a “dragon”?**

---

I’ve come to this question after looking at a few different productions of the opera *Die Zauberflöte* (*The Magic Flute*) by Schikaneder and Mozart.  In the opening scene, Prince Tamino is battling “der listigen Schlange” (“the cunning serpent”).  Some depictions have this creature as a snake, whereas others have a dragon (it is doesn’t really make any difference to the story).  Does this choice of word leave the beast’s identity the up to interpretation, or are the versions that use a dragon embellishing?

Comment: To me I'd not have that association, but historically it might (e.g. see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drache_(Mythologie) )

Comment: If you want to be strict about it, "Drache" is the mythological creature and "Schlange" is the animal in the suborder Serpentes. But keep in mind that the opera has a mythological setting where such distinctions aren't very important and production designers can (and do) make their own interpretation. You can similarly call a dragon a "wyrm" in English, even though a dragon is not much like a worm. FWIW the [Classics Explained video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0G-_4p4rVlo) calls it a snake, but I've also seen productions where it's more of a dragon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in old texts, *Schlange* was used to refer to "dragon", similar as *Drache* and *Lindwurm*. [In Middle High German, *slange* meant "snake", "dragon", or "devil"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schlange). I yet have to find some reference from New High German, but I remember having read *Schlange* being used to refer to a dragon in New High German texts.

As dragons are fictional, there does not seem to always have been a canonical idea of how they are supposed to look. I guess, there was a time when people imagined them to look like snakes a little, as the term *Lindwurm* (a dragon-like being or even a subspecies of dragon) suggests. The first part of the word stems from Old Norse *linnr* meaning "snake". [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Drache_(Mythologie)) says about the dragons from Greek mythology:

> Bei den griechischen Drachen überwiegt der Schlangenaspekt,

(Within the greek dragons, the aspect of the serpents is predominant.)

Also, in the Christian tradition, both dragons and snakes were used as a metaphor or an incarnation of the evil and the devil.

Nonetheless, in current German, *Schlange* does not have the meaning "dragon" any more.

Comment: There's the theory that dragons are kind of a hybrid of the subconscious fears of the big predators our ancestors had to fear way back when: Big cats, birds of prey and large snakes. Think of one of those taking a poor little _Homo habilis_ for lunch. So it makes sense that in most (all?) variations, dragons have aspects of snakes, just more or less pronounced.

Comment: The opera premiered in 1791, does this count as an “older text”; would *Schlange* have been ambiguous at the time?

Comment: @ElementsInSpace I would say so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the German word “Schlange” just as ambiguous as “serpent” is in English; can it refer to a “dragon”?

Answered out of a native speaker's view of the german language that people speak today, both no.

I don't know if perhaps in older books or plays or sayings the word "Schlange" had different meanings. But in today's language one wouldn't think of a dragon when "Schlange" is mentioned.

There is the word "Lindwurm", a fantasy / myth creature that seems to have a wider range of interpretation. I have no definition of that but if you look for images of a Lindwurm, you will find looks that all tend to be some kind of worm with dragon-like wings.

Last but not least, "Schlange" is the german word for "queue" too. That in fact is an ambiguity, but far from the one you mentioned.